# Accessing a button name of a function (member)

Tags: swift

I am trying to access a button name with in a function `configButtonLH()` and the button name `menuButtonLH`. The concept is you tap the button, the menu expands, you make your selection, and it hides `menuButtonLH`. That part works. I have an `onTap()` function that I want to use to unhide it but I can't access `menuButtonLH`.

I've tried but no luck:

```
@objc func onTap() {
    let LH = configButtonLH()
    LH.isHidden = True 

    self.preview.isHidden = true
    self.lockScreen.isHidden = true
    // cancel button
    self.pageOutlet.isHidden = false // dismiss button is not hidden
}

fileprivate func configButtonLH() {
    let menuButtonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 64.0, height: 64.0)
    let menuButtonLH = ExpandingMenuButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: menuButtonSize), image: UIImage(named: "buttonA")!, rotatedImage: UIImage(named: "buttonAL")!)
    menuButtonLH.center = CGPoint(x: 30, y: self.view.bounds.height - 65)
    self.view.addSubview(menuButtonLH)
    // button settings
    menuButtonLH.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    menuButtonLH.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    menuButtonLH.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 6)
    menuButtonLH.menuTitleDirection = .right
    menuButtonLH.bottomViewAlpha = 0.09
    //menuButton2.alpha = 0

    //  Lets hide the right button
    let item1 = ExpandingMenuItem(size: menuButtonSize, title: "Home Screen", image: UIImage(named: "icon")!, highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-icon-place-highlighted")!, backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button"), backgroundHighlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button-highlighted")) { () -> Void in
        self.preview.isHidden = false
        self.pageOutlet.isHidden = true
       // menuButton2.alpha = 0
    }

    let item2 = ExpandingMenuItem(size: menuButtonSize, title: "Lock Screen", image: UIImage(named: "lock")!, highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-icon-place-highlighted")!, backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button"), backgroundHighlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button-highlighted")) { () -> Void in
        //  showAlert "Share"
        self.lockScreen.isHidden = false
        self.pageOutlet.isHidden = true
        menuButtonLH.isHidden = true
    }

    menuButtonLH.addMenuItems([item1, item2])

    menuButtonLH.willPresentMenuItems = { (menu) -> Void in
        print("MenuItems will present.")
    }

    menuButtonLH.didDismissMenuItems = { (menu) -> Void in
        print("MenuItems dismissed.")
        // menuButton2.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

And here is the onTap function:

```
@objc func onTap() {
    self.preview.isHidden = true
    self.lockScreen.isHidden = true
    // cancel button
    self.pageOutlet.isHidden = false // dismiss button is not hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, menuButtonLH is defined within the scope of the function "configButtonLH." It is invisible outside the function.

The class containing these functions is presumably a view controller?

You can define it as an instance property of that class, like so:

```
var menuButtonLH: ExpandingMenuButton!
```

It has to be "var" so you can initialize it after the object is initialized, and an unwrapped optional as long as you're guaranteeing that it will get initialized before use.

Added:

The only unwrapped optionals I see in the code you posted are the failable initializers in these calls:

```
    let menuButtonLH = ExpandingMenuButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: menuButtonSize), image: UIImage(named: "buttonA")!, rotatedImage: UIImage(named: "buttonAL")!)

    //  Lets hide the right button
    let item1 = ExpandingMenuItem(size: menuButtonSize, title: "Home Screen", image: UIImage(named: "icon")!, highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-icon-place-highlighted")!, backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button"), backgroundHighlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button-highlighted"))

    let item2 = ExpandingMenuItem(size: menuButtonSize, title: "Lock Screen", image: UIImage(named: "lock")!, highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-icon-place-highlighted")!, backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button"), backgroundHighlightedImage: UIImage(named: "chooser-moment-button-highlighted"))
```

If one of them is causing the fault, odds are that for some reason one or more of your images can't be found.

The debugger should be telling you where the program is blowing up.

Comment: its ```class PageViewController: PageboyViewController ``` i've also tried that and it crashes once i tap on the screen

Comment: once i get home from work ill look at it again && post it.

Comment: ```Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
2019-04-22 18:43:16.418992-0500 TheWall[5643:159672] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value``` thats the error